# Convert html element to dojo Node?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I tried doing

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
var nodeList = new query.NodeList();
nodeList.push(div);
nodeList.children(".someClass");
// I get error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLDivElement] has no method 'children'
```

So I'm guessing I have to convert the html element to a dojo Node element? How do you do this?

Also, do you know of a better way to query an element's children nodes (based on children's classNames), when given a parent as an htmlElement variable with no id or class, and children with classNames?

thx to craig swing for the explanation

Comment: Will using the DOJO parser help? A good link is at http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/parser.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read Node in the documentation, it is referring to a dom node and not anything specific to Dojo.

If you are looking to create a new dom node, then you should use dom-construct.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/dom-construct.html

Given a particular node, you can query for all of its children using the following:

```
var parentNode = ...
dojo.query('> *', parentNode).forEach(....);
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/query.html#dojo-query

Comment: how do I query all children and their children?

Answer (score 1):

`dijit.findWidgets(DOMNode)` finds and returns widgets within the DOMNode. This will return all the top level widgets in that DOMNode.